# To show the very large data on the ui grid

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

```
public List<PropertyListDto> GetPropertiesByStatus(GetPropertyInput input)
        {

            //exception occurs here
            var properties = _propertyRepository
                .GetAll()
                .Include(p => p.Address)
                .ToList();

            var results = new List<PropertyListDto>(properties.OrderBy(p => p.Id).MapTo<List<PropertyListDto>>());
           return results;

        }



[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Property))]
    public class PropertyListDto : FullAuditedEntityDto
    {
        public new int Id { get; set; }
        public CountyListDto County { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public string Dist { get; set; }
        public decimal ListingPrice { get; set; }
        public string Blk { get; set; }
        public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Lot { get; set; }
        public decimal Taxes { get; set; }
        public string Mls { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CommentEditDto> Comments { get; set; }
        public int? LegacyId { get; set; }
    }
```

Q : I need to show around 100,000 (1 lakh) data on the Angular UI Grid.But the problem is, above query gives memory exception.So could you tell me how to sort out this issue ? Thanks.

**Note :** I need to show the data without pagination.So I have selected this [UI Grid.](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/404_large_data_sets_and_performance)

**UPDATE :**

When I use `.AsNoTracking()`, then it works fine on the first query.

```
var properties = _propertyRepository
                .GetAll()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(p => p.Address)
                .ToList();
```

But then the problem is on `MapTo` line.Could you tell me how to sort it out ? Thanks.

```
 var results = new List<PropertyListDto>(properties.OrderBy(p => p.Id).MapTo<List<PropertyListDto>>());//error is here now
```

This is the error :

```
{"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}

Mapping types:
Property_A048C3D093990BB6A086B710BAC90CB35FD4BAB180FC02FA3E90053FE58F20D3 -> ICollection`1
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Property_A048C3D093990BB6A086B710BAC90CB35FD4BAB180FC02FA3E90053FE58F20D3 -> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[IP.Comments.Dtos.CommentEditDto,IP.Application, Version=1.7.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Destination path:
List`1[3126].Comments3126[3126].Comments3126[3126]

Source value:
[Property_A048C3D093990BB6A086B710BAC90CB35FD4BAB180FC02FA3E90053FE58F20D3 3166]
```

**UPDATE 2 :** Here I have used `Automapper` to map EF object into Dto object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are initiate two ToList methods since I do not know what MapTo doing.
However instead doing mapping select directly your dto:

```
var properties = _propertyRepository
                .GetAll()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(p => p.Address).
                .Select(s=> new PropertyListDto{
                        Id = s.Id
                        CountyListDto = s.CountyListDto 
                         ...    


})
```

**OP's Answer :** Actually I have reduced all the unnecessary data on the above table and now it's having around 1K+ records.So no problem at all now.Cheers :)

Comment: Here I have used Automapper to map EF object into Dto object.Thanks.

Comment: Actually the above mapping (on my post) is working fine with the small number of records.The problem is with big set of records.Do you know why ? Thanks.

Comment: Because you are coping one list to another in mapping. Either try to use my code or Automapper Queryable Extensions https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions